# Understand microservices when learning nestJS

Tags: microservices, nestjs

I started studying rabbitmq, and how can I not understand how microservices communicate through gateway. Can you understand when studying nestJS, microservices architecture, gateway, how they communicate?

[image]

Comment: Do you have an example of what sort of "communication" you want explained?

Comment: @Alex Wayne i can't figure out how to api gateway? understands what service to request, and how services communicate through it? 
attached the image in the question

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't completely clear since you're talking about both RabbitMQ and API Gateways which aren't necessarily overlapping concepts. In the attached screenshot you've provided the API Gateway communicates with all of the downstream services over REST (HTTP Protocol). So the API Gateway acts as a single domain/endpoint from the perspective of downstream clients interacting with the system but internally the gateway maintains routing rules for how to send the right requests to the right downstream services

Comment: Sorry, I picked up the wrong picture, let's assume that there will be the amqp protocol. I understand that gateway is a single entry point where all requests will be sent, my study started from an article about microservices, and it shows a simple example with the micromq and rabbitmq package, but I still don't understand how gateway will communicate with microservices. After I saw that there are microservices in nestJS, and I thought, maybe studying this framework will help me figure it out

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be mixing concepts here. Microservices can communicate synchronously (e.g. by RESTful HTTP APIs) or asynchronously (e.g. using RabbitMQ with AMQP protocol).

**API-Gateway**: An API Gateway is a facade (or single point of access) for multiple or all microservice. Often it also contains features like service discovery (locating service instances) and load balancing across instances. Usually it is used for synchronous communication between microservices or as interface for clients.

**Message Broker**: A message broker (like RabbitMQ) enables you to use publish-subscribe, usually between microservices. This also includes service discovery (by each instance registering at the broker to consume messages) and load balancing (for example by using consumer groups). It is used for asynchronous communication between microservices, usually not with clients.

Depending if your system has synchronous or asynchronous communication (or both), you will have an API gateway, a message broker, or both. But they are usually not intertwined. Maybe using the gateway to route to the message broker - but that's it.

Comment: In the Russian-speaking segment, I did not find good lessons on microservices (or I was looking badly), but in English, it is difficult to understand only leash from video.
Okay, if I don't use gateway, should I start learning nestJS to get a deeper understanding of the concept of microservices?

Comment: I think the technology nestJS is independent from the concept of microservices. If you want to learn about microservices you should look into that specifically. There are books, e.g. by Sam Newman or Eberhard Wolff, that could offer a good starting point for you.